# sequential key generator (java)

Tags: java, key, generator, sequential

I am trying to (sequentially) generate keys from letters a-z and A-Z, numbers 0-9, other characters like (){}[]~!@#$%^&*()_+`-=|\;:'"<,>.?/ or any combination of those sets. My real problem, however, is that the key needs to increase in length until my base case is found.
If anyone has a suggestion or a solution, any help and/or explanations would be much appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: @MrSmith42 Yes, but I couldn't get past the set of characters and some of their permutations. Unfortunately, I don't have my code right now, but it's nothing special, and their were no errors, e.g., it accomplished what it was intended to do, but didn't achieve the overall goal.

Comment: Sorry I don't have the code, but I would really appreciate it if you could still help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understood right you want to make a recursive wordlist generator function, in order to check every word with your base case word. [This](http://iexploit.org/index.php?p=/discussion/2965/beginner-programming-how-to-make-a-wordlist-generator/p1) web site might help you with that. The only thing you have to do is to write the code that compares the two words.

Comment: Thats exactly correct, and the website is perfect! Thanks so much!